# Login to application with GET/POST token

Tags: security, authentication, symfony1, token

I work on a Symfony web application which has a standard login form. To allow users to login more easily we want to give them a link which logs them in directly. I've already build a way to get a token to use, but I have no clue as to how the Symfony login process works, specifically how I can adapt it to take a GET/POST token instead of redirecting to the login page. 
Any help appreciated!

Oh and this is Symfony 1.2 BTW (and no, upgrading is not an option right now)

Comment: Please don't build the feature - its a security loophole.

Comment: You mean when someone intercepts the token? We have taken care of that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tom, what I ended up doing was building a second login module/action (I already had a executeLogin action which basically sets the $this->getUser() and $this->getUser()->setAuthenticated(true) when the username/password is correct) with a token instead of username/password.
Some things to take into account on security: either clear up your token when used in a successful login attempt or set something of an expiration timestamp when creating the token. This way a bot can't 'guess' a token.

Comment: I'm sorry Prasad, I can't since I left the company I built it for ;)

Comment: Hi Henri, long time since this thread. I implemented something on the exact lines of what you mentioned here. Setting the user object is the only thing that needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are any differences with regard to this in 1.2 compared to 1.4, but in 1.4 I'd suggest taking a look at the sfGuardPlugin's signin() method (or that of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) to figure out a suitable solution.

```
$this->getUser()->signIn(... params ...);
```

That single call will take care of authentication so I think all you really need to do is to resolve your link-specific stuff beforehand (e.g. validate and fetch sfguarduser username & password from db) and then call that method with the user-specific params. Looking at the method will show you exactly what you're passing into it and how it's being used. It's the same one as is being used in the post action of the login form.

Hope that points you in the right direction.